# Convert HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> to a normal String

Tags: java, azure

I am writing a Java Azure program that builds an envelope and logs the data to Application Insights in the Azure Portal. Currently it is tailored to just accept an HTTP Request function, but I am trying to make it compatible with using the Azure Service Bus and other services as well. My cf.buildEnvelope() function currently is structed as: buildEnvelope(HttpRequestMessage<Optional> req, ExecutionContext context)
and I want to change it to:
buildEnvelope(String req, ExecutionContext context) so that I can use it for more than just the HTTP Request. In order to do this I believe I just need to convert my req to a normal String in my Handler, but I cannot figure out how to do so.

Here is my Handler:

```
`import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpMethod;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpResponseMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpStatus;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;
//import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.ServiceBusQueueTrigger;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Handler {
    @FunctionName("HttpHandler")
    public HttpResponseMessage runHttp(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> req, ExecutionContext context) {
        
    Optional<String> payload = req.getBody();
    // payload to String (Ignore this)
    //String payload2 = req.getBody().orElse("");


    MessageEnvelope envelope = cf.buildEnvelope(req, context);
    cf.log(envelope, context, payload);

    return req.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Data logged").build();
    }
}`
```

And my buildEnvelope function:

```
`public static MessageEnvelope buildEnvelope(HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> req, ExecutionContext context) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    Optional<String> payload = req.getBody();

   MessageEnvelope msgEnvelope = new MessageEnvelope(req, context);
   msgEnvelope.setMessageMetadata(new MessageMetadata(System.getenv("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT"), System.getenv("USERDNSDOMAIN")));
   msgEnvelope.setMessageAttributes(new MessageAttributes("", ""));
   msgEnvelope.setMessageParameters(new MessageParameters("", ""));
   msgEnvelope.setMessageVariable(new String[]{"0", "1", "2"});
   msgEnvelope.setMessagePayload(gson.toJson(payload));

   return msgEnvelope;
}`
```

Please help me make this conversion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

You should be able to call `String payload2 = req.getBody().get();` to get the string value out of the `Optional<String>` class